# Installing a puppet module on master with Puppetfile

Tags: puppet

I'm using R10K to manage my configuration files.

I want to install a puppet module on my master server using a Puppet file.

I go to the branch and add the following to `Puppetfile`:

```
mod 'puppetlabs-certregen', '0.2.0'
```

I then run `puppet agent -t` on the server. It seems the command is successful, in that the commands in my manifest are run, but when I run `puppet certregen healthcheck` the module doesn't seem to be installed.

What's the correct way to use the Puppetfile to install a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Puppetfile is similar to a Ruby Gemfile, Python requirements.txt: it lists dependancies which are then installed by a separate tool.

For Puppetfiles, this is [r10k](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k).

It's documented here https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2018.1/puppetfile.html

You can also directly download the module with the command line:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-certregen
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppet.com ...
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/Users/petersouter/.puppetlabs/etc/code/modules
└─┬ puppetlabs-certregen (v0.2.0)
  └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.17.1)
```

Note, however, that r10k and `puppet module install` [don't play well together](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/modules_installing.html):

> Restriction: If you are using Code Manager or r10k, do not install, update, or uninstall modules with the `puppet module` command. With code management, you must install modules with a Puppetfile. Code management purges modules that were installed with the puppet module command. See the [Puppetfile documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/latest/puppetfile.html) for instructions.

Comment: On old versions of ruby (<2.3) you can install `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem install librarian-puppet`, add `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin` to path and just do `librarian-puppet update` in the folder with Puppetfile.